# Full width and height of an image inside divs

Tags: jquery, css, background, fullscreen

So i need some help here.

I made this setup were i need some images to allways be full screen (scaled to fit) the div the are placed inside. This is how far i have come and no matter what i do i cant get it to work. I really hope someone can help me fix this, its driving me crazy! I have try to put in code like this

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
```

but then the image disseappears... Here is m entire code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="navigation_top">
    <ul>
        <li>Btn_1</li>
        <li>Btn_2</li>
        <li>Btn_3</li>
        <li>Btn_4</li>
        <li>Btn_5</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="navigation_side">
       <ul>        
          <li><a href="#slice1" id="btn_1" class="anchorLink">slice1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#slice2" id="btn_2" class="anchorLink">slice2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#slice3" id="btn_3" class="anchorLink">slice3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#slice4" id="btn_4" class="anchorLink">slice4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#slice5" id="btn_5" class="anchorLink">slice5</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="slice1"></div>
    <div id="slice2"></div>
    <div id="slice3"></div>
    <div id="slice4"></div>
    <div id="slice5"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {height:100%; color:#FFF;}

ul, ol, li {margin:0px!important; padding:0px!important;}

.wrapper {width:100%; height:100%;}
.navigation_top {width:100%; height:50px; line-height:50px; background-color:#000; opacity:.5; position:fixed;}
.navigation_top ul {list-style:none;}
.navigation_top ul li {float:left; width:100px; text-align:center;}
.navigation_top ul li a {display:block; color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;}



.navigation_side {width:200px; height:auto; position:fixed; background-color:#000; opacity:.5; margin-top:10%;}
.navigation_side ul li a {color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;}


#slice1 {width:100%; height:100%; background:url(http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/6018/image1uii.jpg);}
#slice2 {width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#999;}
#slice3 {width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#888;}
#slice4 {width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#777;}
#slice5 {width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#666;}
```

**JQUERY**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".anchorLink").click(function(event){        
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    });

    $('.navigation_top').hide();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        // the 10 below is the number of pixels down to show the menu
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) $('.navigation_top').show();
        else $('.navigation_top').hide();
    });
});
```

and also here is a fiddle of my progress: http://jsfiddle.net/iBertel/qLTQ9/

Comment: Which element are you trying to set the "fullscreen" image to?  You aren't assigning it to anything in the CSS.

Comment: each of the slices need their own "fullscreen" image inside em... now just the first has an image and rest have colors - in the end they will each have their own picture which should fill out that div... Hope you understand what i meen? EDIT: Basicly it should be as it is now with colors, just instead of different colors in the slices it should be pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the best way to fit to screen? I would approach it a little differently just because of cencerns regarding image resolution.

The way I would do it is I first check the width/height of screen. Then I compare that to width/height of the image. Then if the image is larger that the screen, I would compress it down and this would allow me to fit it to the screen.

If the image is smaller than the screen, then I center the image in the div and set the color of the div background to be something nice (for example, make sure it is a black div if this matches your site colors).

Put in mind, you have to check the width/height of your image in relation to that of the screen. For example, if the image is too wide for the screen, but not as high, then the image should be scaled down with the width/heigh ratio mantained, so it will be displayed as a horizontal rectangle inside your div. This way your images will not be distorted.

Comment: Remember i need full size images inside each of the 5 divs. 

Its not possible to make the image i load inside the DIV to fit the DIVS size (width:100% height:100% ?) Problem is that i have 5 divs that should be underneath each other, each with their own images and it needs to be responsive so that no matter what browser size im in, it should just scale to fit that view. 

Also im not so strong with jquery. I really need som assistence here.

Comment: Same concept just modified a little. You find the size of your screen, then calculate the sizes of your divs. Based on that, you do your calculations for the images. Remember that you should always count for width/height ratios for the images. You said you do not know much about jQuery, well this is the perfect project for you to learn.

Comment: Indeed - just i need this done by tomorrow :) Anyways if you see this link: http://www.adidas.dk/ - you see the top slider, thats what i need and then just 5 under each other. You got time to help? EDIT: Actually i doesnt need to be 100% height, just 100% width off cause... Maybe this will make it easier.

Comment: Sorry dude, I really have not got anytime, late on my project as well. But to be honest, you should negotiate changing your deadline if this should be done tomorrow. I wish I could help more, but too busy. By the way, I did this thing before, and it does take time.